# Convert a string to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a problem where I need to convert a string to date like

11 years 10 months 12 days to a date in SQL Server.

Please help any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What date would you expect to be? A date in sql is a point in time, not a range. Also, which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012 and I just need date no time. Any date format is valid

Comment: You can compare this 11 years 10 months 12 days from current date and then calculate the date

Comment: please clarify exactly what you require.Despite reading your question 2/3 times I failed to understand anything.People have no time to read what is going on your mind.

Comment: So to get a date you would use the DATE datatype. When you say compare 11 years 10 months 12 days to the current date what does that mean? Do you want to parse that nonsensical string into something usable and then add that many days to the current date? Help us to help you by providing some details here.

Comment: In a table I have a column since date and it has a value like 11 years 10 months 12 days.

Comment: So I just need to convert this string to a date which means to since date

Comment: in a date there you have a calendar year like 2016 and what do you want with 11 as a year?

Comment: I will give and example if I say since date is 0 years 0 months 2 days then date would be 27 Feb 2016.

Comment: So you want to subtract that many days from the current date? And what have you tried? And why are you storing your data like that?

Comment: I am not storing I am migrating data from a database I have datetime format in my table and in other table I have this format as string so need to convert this string to a text

Comment: OK. So what have you tried? How consistent is this external data?

Comment: So far we have seen several people attempt to decipher your cryptic description of the problem but we have not seen any effort on your own.

Comment: See the answers below a guy is very close I don't know when will you understand the issue and when will you try to solve it

Comment: @YashShukla - You are not supposed talk like this Sean Lange is trying to help you

Comment: I understand you are frustrated but you are the one getting paid for this not me. Sure I could "solve" this for you but what are you going to do next time, find somebody to do your work for you again? Good luck. I like to teach people to fish, not hand them a filleted fish.

Comment: I find it sad that you feel so entitled to get an answer with little to no information up front. Then when asking for details you started getting at angry at me for trying to understand your problem so that somebody would be able to help you. You should try to demonstrate a little bit of empathy and patience with the people trying to help you. It will help you not just on forums but in life in general. Good luck and I hope you find your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50)= '1 year 12 months 2 days'
DECLARE @days   INT= LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)),
        @months INT = Substring(@str, Charindex('months', @str) - 3, 2),
        @years  INT = Substring(@str, Charindex('days', @str) - 3, 2);

WITH days_back
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(day, -@days, Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)) AS day_date),
     month_back
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(month, -@months, day_date) AS month_date
         FROM   days_back)
SELECT Result = Dateadd(year, -@years, month_date)
FROM   month_back
```

Comment: This logic I can use but biggest fight how to split string like need to separate years months days from 12 years 11 months 10 days

Comment: @YashShukla - updated my answer to extract values from string

Comment: Yes like this now we can separate number with first space but my value is a single string so is there any way to separate from a single string like separate year month and date from '1 year 2 months 2 days'. You are very close..

Comment: @YashShukla Will the string be always in this format  **1 year 2 months 2 days**

Comment: Yes it will always be in this format x years y months  z days

Comment: Yesss thanks a lot man you did it all other guys are still thinking what is the problem you are great thanks a lot

Comment: @YashShukla - Its not like how you are thinking. They just want yo put some effort to solve your problem thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @fuzzy_date varchar(255) = '11 years 10 months 12 days'

declare @date date
declare @startdate date = '1999-12-31'
declare @today_to_before date = getdate()
declare @today_to_after date = getdate()

declare @years int, @months int, @days int, @foo varchar(255)

Set @years = left(@fuzzy_date, charindex('years', @fuzzy_date) - 1)

Select @fuzzy_date = right(@fuzzy_date, len(@fuzzy_date) - charindex('years', @fuzzy_date) - 5)

select @months = left(@fuzzy_date, charindex('months', @fuzzy_date) - 1)

Select @days = replace(right(@fuzzy_date, len(@fuzzy_date) - charindex('months', @fuzzy_date) - 6), 'days', '')

Select @years, @months, @days

Set @date = dateadd(yy, @years, @startdate)
Set @date = dateadd(mm, @months, @date)
Set @date = dateadd(dd, @days, @date)


Set @today_to_after = dateadd(yy, @years, @today_to_after)
Set @today_to_after = dateadd(mm, @months, @today_to_after)
Set @today_to_after = dateadd(dd, @days, @today_to_after)

Set @today_to_before = dateadd(yy, -@years, @today_to_before)
Set @today_to_before = dateadd(mm, -@months, @today_to_before)
Set @today_to_before = dateadd(dd, -@days, @today_to_before)
Select @date,@today_to_after,@today_to_before
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want but only with one change istead of start date and can we take current date as reference and then subtract it to calculate date?

Comment: @YashShukla you should be able to handle that minor adjustment on your own?

Comment: I am.not that experienced in sql

Comment: I edited the answer. The result you expected, now, probably is "@today_to_before" column